# Why cannot I use this.props in stateless functions like I did in React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

When I used props in react Components,I used this.props.name to access `name`.

```
this.state = {
    seconds:parseInt(this.props.start)
};
```

But when I do the same thing in functions [stateless],I get an error:

```
function Show(props) {
    return (
        <p>Hello {this.props.name}!</p>
    );
}
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Because props are passed in as a parameter, not set as a property. Look at the code you've written, you can see it in the function definition.

Comment: because there is no `this` in FunctionComponents, only the passed argement(s)

Comment: @AnaSvitlica you have given a clear explanation. Thanks

Comment: Except @AnaSvitlica's explanation isn't 100% correct. `Show` is certainly a react component. Stateless vs stateful is old, dead nomenclature. Class-based components can be stateless and functional components can be stateful.

Answer (score 1):

if `name` is being passed to `Show`, then you'd just get it from `props.name` instead of `this.props.name`

i.e. if this is happening somewhere:

```
<div>
  <Show name="The Simpsons" />
</div>
```

then you can access it like this:

```
function Show(props) {
  return <p>Hello {props.name}!</p>;
}
```

or you can destructure the name out of props, like this:

```
function Show({ name }) {
  return <p>Hello {name}!</p>;
}
```